# Ion-input issue. undefined value when trying to bind prodbum.totalamt. What might be the issue?

Tags: typescript, ionic2

Ion-input issue. undefined value when trying to bind prodbum.totalamt. What might be the problem?

username

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Secondname</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number"  name="secondname" [(ngModel)]="prodbum.secondname" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Total: {{prodbum.username * prodbum.secondname}}</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" [value]="prodbum.username * prodbum.secondname" [(ngModel)]= "prodbum.totalamt"  readonly="true"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
```

Comment: why use both `value` and `ngModel`?

Comment: @ Suraj I am passing its value from the first and second ion-input to the third ion-input. The value of the third input is the multiplication of the first and second input. Now I want to access the input of the third ion-input through the [(ngModel)]. What should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use change event for this and set your `prodbum.totalamt` in the component side.

For example:

```
 <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Secondname</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number"  name="secondname" [(ngModel)]="prodbum.secondname" (change)="findProd()" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Total: {{prodbum.username * prodbum.secondname}}</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]= "prodbum.totalamt"  readonly="true"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
```

In component create `findProd()` function:

```
    findProd(){
     if(prodbum.username && prodbum.secondname){
       prodbum.totalamt=prodbum.username * prodbum.secondname;
     }
   }
```

You can call the same function from the `change` event of the first input.